# Trying JQuery-UI to create modal in MVC project

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using MVC 5/C#. I'm trying to follow the example found here: [JQuery-ui in MVC5](http://blog.falafel.com/three-steps-use-jquery-ui-asp-net-mvc-5/)
This has me add JQuery-UI with NuGet, which I did.

Here is what I have in my Index.cshtml:

```
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Get Form" onclick="getForm()" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getForm() {
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            width: 400,
            resizable: false,
            title: 'Register',
            modal: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {

                $(this).load('@Url.Action("Register", "Registration")');
            },
            buttons: {
                "Close": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    }</script>

<div id="dialog"></div>
```

Here is what is in my _Layout.cshmtl file:

```
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/scripts")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
```

Here is what is in my BundleConfig.cs (paths are correct):

```
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add
        (
            // Ensure that "bootstrap.3.3.4.min.css" also exists in the directory so that it's used for minification, or else minification will fail.
            new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css")
                .Include
                (
                    "~/Content/css/bootstrap.3.3.4.css", 
                    "~/Content/css/sticky-footer.css",
                    "~/Content/css/style.css"
                )
        );

        bundles.Add
        (
            new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts")
                .Include
                (
                    "~/Content/JS/jquery.1.11.2.js",
                    "~/Content/JS/bootstrap.3.3.4.js",
                    "~/Content/JS/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"
                )
        );

        bundles.Add
        (
            new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css")
            .Include
            (
                "~/Content/themes/base/core.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/resizable.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/selectable.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/accordion.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/autocomplete.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/button.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/dialog.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/slider.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/tabs.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/datepicker.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/progressbar.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/theme.css"
            )
        );
    }
```

I get the javascript errors:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
>     $.ui @ jquery-ui-1.11.4.js:14
>     (anonymous function) @ jquery-ui-1.11.4.js:16
>   Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function

I'm guessing the '.dialog is not a function' error is because jQuery-ui-1.11.4 is not loading correctly. Do I have a version mis-match or something?

Comment: I just tried moving the ui script to /Content/JS and updating the BundleConfig.cs. Still not working.

Comment: I think I found the issue. The order the scripts are listed in the rendered html. <script src="/Content/JS/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script> comes right before 
<script src="/Content/JS/jquery.1.11.2.js"></script>!!! Perhaps I should put UI in a separate ScriptBundle, then Render that later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like jQuery ui isn't loaded on the page or it is loaded before jQuery. Check view source of the page to check the order correctness of included libraries.

Comment: The only way I was able to get this to be ordered/loaded correctly was to create a second Script bundle for the jQuery-ui, and load that in the Layout file second. I have also seen some posts about Ordering the bundles, but haven't tried those, it is working now.